# Attempting to write the times table using a for loop and sending it to a label c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I'm attempting to do the above, but each iteration keeps over-writing the last.

```cs
if (timestablevalid == true)
{
    timestable = Convert.ToInt32(temptimestable);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 13; counter++)
    {
        lblShowTimesTable.Text = (counter + "times" + timestable + " =" + counter * timestable + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

I tried the above "Environment.NewLine", I also tried the "\n" thing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah it would do that... you're not retaining the previous value of `lblShowTimesTable.Text` anywhere (perhaps you might want to add a `lblShowTimesTable.Text + ` in there somewhere?)

Comment: If i gave you 10 apples and you kept on throwing the last one away, you only have one apple...

Comment: The difference between `=` and `+=` here: `someLabel.Text = "something";` overwrites the old value, while `someLabel.Text += "something";` appends to the old value.

Answer (score 1):

When appending to string, it is better to use StringBuilder class, since each appending to string creates a new string (strings are immutable).
Once the loop is finished, the result value should be set to TextBox

```
if (timestablevalid == true)
{
    timestable = Convert.ToInt32(temptimestable);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 13; counter++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(counter + "times" + timestable + " =" + counter * timestable);
    }

    lblShowTimesTable.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This clears the label between runs. It's not clear if the poster wanted this.

Comment: In general the advice about using `StringBuilder` instead of `+=` when building a string with the use of a loop, is correct. However, with a loop of running 13 times and short strings like here, it is not much "pressure" you put on the memory management. So no harm from keeping `+=`. However, in a more performance critical application, and when the loop is encounter extremely many times, it can matter.

Comment: You could wonder if the expression `counter + "times" + timestable + " =" + counter * timestable` is evaluated in a way that creates nine strings in total, or if the C# compiler and/or .NET runtime will optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rewrite:

```cs
if (timestablevalid) // No need to compare a boolean to true or false, just use it
{
    timestable = Convert.ToInt32(temptimestable);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 13; counter++)
    {
        // Use interpolated string for higher readability  
        lblShowTimesTable.Text+= $"{counter} times {timestable} = {counter * timestable}\n";
        // and last but not least use the += operator
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirements you might want to clear the label before entering the loop.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I knew what I wanted to do just lacked the "vocabulary" to do it!!  Fist time posting here, I'm surprised there no donate function I'd throw you a coffee for that alone :)

Comment: @nail3r You can always accept Palle's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this please.

```
lblShowTimesTable.Text += (counter + "times" + timestable + " =" + counter * timestable + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Yes, `+=` works by retrieving the property `Text` by calling the `get` accessor (getter), then concatenating the retrieved string with the string expression on the right (the parenthesis is not actually needed), and finally writing it back to the property with the `set` accessor (setter) of the property. So it can be "fixed" with the insertion of a single character.